How can I get precise location of a robot?
So I am developing a robot that needs precise location data. In the area i have 2G, or 3G communication but the problem is the GPS Antenna may be covered up with a plastic box. How can I achieve precise location data in this case?

how do you achieve precise location data without the plastic box?
